# Internal Server Error, while accessing field in apex

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, aura

In one of my methods, I'm getting an internal server error, when I'm trying to access one field value.

I guess it's because of the way I'm trying to access the field.

```
@AuraEnabled
public static string createABAData(List<ABA_Data__c> abaPDataList,string parentId){
        for(ABA_Data__c abaProgram : abaPDataList){
            Boolean isFirst = true;
            system.debug('>>> function... '+abaProgram);
            //system.debug('>>> function type... '+abaProgram.Notes__c); // getting error while trying to access notes field
}
```

This is the value I'm receiving in the first debug logs

**ABA_Data__c:{Notes__c=[value 1, value2], Date_Recorded__c=2021-02-08 00:00:00}**

What's the reason I'm getting this error when I'm trying to access the field value?

the parameters to this method is passed from Aura Component

Answer (score 1):

```
ABA_Data__c:{Notes__c=[value 1, value2], Date_Recorded__c=2021-02-08 00:00:00}
                      ^-? bad value ?-^
```

You need to convert this value to the appropriate data type for Notes__c, probably a String. This should be reported as a bug to Salesforce, but in the interim, fixing the data to the correct type before calling the method should fix the problem.

Comment: this is of multi select picklist type

Comment: @sfdc Do the values you're passing in match the API names of the select list?

Comment: Yes it matches with the API names, I'm able to access other fields. I guess it's because of the format of multi-select picklist which you already highlighted. This picklist field gets value from duallistbox